# Is there any way to symplify this blit process?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

it's my first time making a game in pygame and i'm starting with the main title screen, just now i realised that there's going to be a lot of buttons to press, and i wonder if there's a way around having to write the blit method for every image file that i want to put in screen.

this is a part of the code i want as the example i want to improve (there'll be a lot more buttons), i just want it to be less redundant and ugly looking

```
    screen.blit(start_button, [20, 30])
    screen.blit(settings_button, [20, 255])
    screen.blit(load_button, [20, 325])
    screen.blit(quit_button, [20, 490])
```

Comment: What is ugly? Use classes. The usual way in Pygame to do this is to use [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around the fact that you have to use every image you want to display somewhere in the code. You can use a list of tuples and a loop:

```py
buttons = [(start_button, [20, 30]), (settings_button, [20, 255]),
    (load_button, [20, 325]), (quit_button, [20, 490])]
for button in buttons:
    pygame.blit(*button)
```

---

However, the usual way to do this in pygame is to the [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html). See [What is the difference between pygame sprite and surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665946/what-is-the-difference-between-pygame-sprite-and-surface), [How can I add objects to a "pygame.sprite.Group()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924256/how-can-i-add-objects-to-a-pygame-sprite-group), [What does pygame.sprite.Group() do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765971/what-does-pygame-sprite-group-do) and many more.

Create a `Button` class, subclass [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite):

```py
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Create a [pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and add the sprites:

```py
button_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
button_group.add(Button(start_button, [20, 30]))
button_group.add(Button(settings_button, [20, 255]))
button_group.add(Button(load_button, [20, 325]))
button_group.add(Button(quit_button, [20, 490]))
```

Draw the buttons of the group in the application loop:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    button_group.draw(scren)

    # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
```